# Does running a query inside a transaction guarantee the uniqueness of the generated number?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

When I change an `OnlinePayment` I want to create a unique `InvoiceNumber` for the record. This code will generate a unique id:

```
int newId = db.OnlinePayments.Max(op => op.InvoiceNumber) + 1;
```

However, this will fail if another record is being added at the same time. Using an `Identity` column is not an option since the `InvoiceNumber` should change whenever I change the database. Would the following code guarantee the uniqueness of the generated `InvoiceNumber`?

```
using (var transaction = db.Database.BeginTransaction())
{
    try
    {
        int newId = db.OnlinePayments.Max(op => op.InvoiceNumber) + 1;
        opi.InvoiceNumber = newId;
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();

        transaction.Commit();
    }
    catch
    {
        transaction.Rollback();
    }
}
```

Comment: Somewhat unclear....`GUID`? `Random Number Generator (RNG)`? come to mind...

Comment: Why not use `InvoiceNumber` as identity column?

Comment: @ArindamNayak I believe I answered your question above.

Comment: @AlirezaNoori I didn't really understand your reasoning, What do you mean by "since the InvoiceNumber should change whenever I change the database"?

Comment: If I set the column as `Identity`, when I can't change the value manually and I want it to change every time I modify the record. Suppose there's a record with the `Id` of `1` and the `InvoiceNumber` of `10`. Now when I change this record the `InvoiceNumber` should change to something like `11`. `Identity` doesn't allow this. At least I don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

No, since two transactions can both read the same max value and then both use that value plus one.

Comment: So how can I do this?

Comment: I can't find a good canonical question right now. Maybe you should ask it. "How to generate contiguous sequential IDs with Entity Framework?".

Comment: Yes I want sequential IDs but I want them to change whenever I modify the record. As I said to Martin above, if there's a record with the `Id` of `1` and the `InvoiceNumber` of `10`. Now when I change this record the `InvoiceNumber` should change to something like `11`.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question. I answered the question as asked and explained why this cannot be relied upon. Ask another question. There's no limit on the number of questions you can ask. Don't derail an existing question.

Comment: This is what I'm looking for. Maybe I needed to add this to my question to explain it more. And I think the title is very much related to what I explained

Comment: I answered your question as asked and your title was very accurate. Ask a new question if you want to change the topic.